# Delete files on SD card after uninstalling app

Tags: android

Is there any way to delete files on SD card after uninstalling my application?
My application saves log files on SD card so users can acces them without any trouble, but I would like to delete them when my app will be uninstalled from phone.

Comment: Your app is not informed if you or a user uninstalls it. So the app can do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you should use External Cache directory to save tour log files which will be automatically deleted by the system when user uninstalls your application.

Here you can learn more about how you can access that directory:
[getExternalCacheDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir())

Or even use `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs()` if there is a secondary external storage available: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalCacheDirs(android.content.Context))